# Installing casing using jack miters

Tags: finishing, trim, butt-joint

I'm looking to match the butt style casing installation of my old home.  Standard 45 mitered casing and planning the backside has worked for me in newer homes

First floor example with backband 
[image: first floor example with backband]

The adjoining room installation method I want to copy. I have freshly routed 1x4 that matches this style. 
[image: the install method I'm wanting to duplicate]

I've never seen trim installed like this, but it intrigues me.

Hopefully you can provide me some insight.

I edited my original question as I originally did not know the name of this cut.  So my answer would be how to correctly measure and cut jack miters for window and door casing.  Specifically how to cut a 45 degree angle through just the decorative part

Comment: Surely you only have to mitre the decorative portions (the mouldings/beadwork) and simply cut the flat boards to length and fit together with butt joints? So two separate operations on different pieces of wood. I don't think it likely but there is a possibility that the corners of the flat portions feature a hidden mitre, what in the US is called a [mitred half-lap](http://images.woodmagazine.mdpcdn.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_hero__450x300/public/image/2016/06/23/Mitered%20opener.jpg).

Comment: For cutting a miter into the beadwork, what would you recommend as a tool / process to do so?  I practiced with my miter saw (powered) and it digs into one side sooner then the other either it's not possible or I'm doing it wrong.   I think a miter box may work but I don't want to do these all by hand.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Apologies for such a poor comment, but must go to work... https://www.infinitytools.com/blog/2016/05/05/how-to-make-a-window-sash-part-1/ -- see the section about 2/3rds down about mitering the detail on the muntins.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, ok I've read this now about thirty times and I still don't quite understand. I have to take apart one joint to remove excessive caulk. I'll add a photo shortly to show what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: Well I just had a revelation it's called a jack miter at least here in the US. So I guess my question should be how to properly cut a jack miter for door casing.

Comment: @Rob http://www.aconcordcarpenter.com/cutting-a-jack-miter.html has a pretty good walkthrough of how to cut a jack miter for exactly your situation.

Comment: @RobertNubel thanks !!  Exactly what I needed